# Disable flash or other plugins in .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, flash, browser

Is it possible to disable Flash Player or any other plugins from being used by the .NET WebBrowser control?

Answer (score 1):

You could access the WebBrowser.Document.HtmlDocument property of the the control to get managed access to the DOM.  From there you can pull out any object tags responsible for loading plugin content...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually been doing that, but I was wondering if there might be something a bit more efficient.

Comment: The WebBrowser control is fairly locked down.  That's pretty much the only approach you can take other than using a low level type such as WebClient.